# simple loop code in C

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

The loop in this program doesn't work as I expect:

```
int main() {
    char userresponse;
    char x;

    do {
        printf("are you human");
        scanf("%c", &userresponse);
        if (userresponse == 'y') {
            printf("welcome");
        }
        if (userresponse == 'y') {
            printf("please leave");
        }
        printf("type z to repeat");
        scanf("%c", &x);
    } while (x == 'z');

    return 0;
}
```

It gets to "type z to repeat", and then it finishes.  When I tried defining `char x='z';` the program runs fine the first time, but at the end it loops like 2 or 4 times, displaying all the `printf` messages, even the `else` ones, in the `if` statements.

I expect the program to wait for input at the bottom of the loop, and to either break out of the loop or continue looping based on that input.  Why isn't it doing that?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. No indentation makes it hard to understand code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. When presenting code here, please indent it in a moderately orthodox style. Lay it out in the edit box as you'd like it too look (ignore the preview), then select the code and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it by four spaces, which makes it appear as code. Your code will be a lot easier to understand if it is indented. As originally presented, it is close to inscrutable. Don't forget to include a newline at the end of outputs that are not prompts (and do include a space at the end of outputs that are prompts).

Comment: when you press `y` and `enter` as input.. it will go 2 characters to your program. You are getting the first `y`.. but there's also the `\n` next.  You can fix by forcing it to ignore new line with [`scanf("%c%*c",&x)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c)

Comment: "even the else ones": There are no `else`s in your program.  There are 2 identical `if`s which produce seemingly opposite results.

Comment: The simplest fix is to use `" %c"` to read characters; it will ignore white space, including newlines, and processes the next character that is not white space.

Comment: as per @ScottHunter, that second `if` should probably be an `else` instead without the if logic.  Or a 'n' check for the letter n.

Comment: Did you step through your debugger?

Answer (score 5):

1. If you enter a character, you implicitly enter another one: the newline, which partially causes the weird behavior. This can be ignored by replacing the format string `"%c"` with `"%c%*c"`.
2. You check for `'y'` twice. Replace the second `'y'` with a `'n'`.
3. Does not influence the program's action but may improve performance: replace the second `if` with an `else if`. This will make the program not even test the condition of the second `if` clause if the first one evaluates to true.
4. You don't check for another character than `y` or `n`. Either add a seperate `else` or, instead of my point 3., replace the second `if` by an `else`<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> As @JonathanLeffler mentioned in the comments to this answer

Comment: Probably better to replace the second `==` with `!=`, or the second `if` with `else`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Done.

Answer (score 4):

When you type in `y` for `userresponse`, you probably have to hit `Enter` after that, right?

`Enter` counts as a charater!  Since it wasn't stored in `userresponse`, it stays in the input buffer.  And the next line to read from the input-buffer is `scanf("%c",&x);`.  So you end up with an `Enter` in the `x` variable.

Next, you described that the program *displays all the printf messages, even the **else** ones,"* 
Do you see the keyword `else` in your program?  (cause I don't)

Answer (score 1):

> but at the end it loops like 2 or 4 times, displaying all the printf messages,

There are several ways to avoid that, one will be to add after scanf this:

```
while((check=getchar()) != EOF && check != '\n');
```

Any way a minimal code will look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char a;
    int check,ok=0;

    do {
        printf("Give an A: ");

        if ((scanf("%c",&a)) == 1){
            while((check=getchar()) != EOF && check != '\n');

            if ((a == 'a') || (a == 'A')){
                printf("True\n");
                ok=0;
            } else {
                printf("False\n");
                ok = 1;
            }
        }else{
            printf("Error");
            exit(1);
        }

    }while (ok == 1);

    return 0;
}
```

But the way how you approach this , a fix will probably look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char userresponse;
    int check,ok=0;
    char x;

    do {
        printf("are you human:  ");

        if ((scanf("%c",&userresponse)) == 1){
            while((check=getchar()) != EOF && check != '\n');

            if ((userresponse == 'y') || (userresponse == 'Y')){
                printf("welcome\n");
                break;
            } else {
                printf("please leave\n\n");
                printf("type z to repeat");
                if(scanf("%c",&x) == 1){
                    while((check=getchar()) != EOF && check != '\n');
                    if(x=='z' || x == 'Z'){
                        ok = 1;
                    }else{
                        printf("\n");
                        printf("Wrong Input\nGoodBye\n");
                        break;
                    }
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }else{
            printf("Error");
            exit(1);
        }

    }while (ok == 1);

    return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying here to explain is that there is no reason to stick with a condition in that while like x=='z', just use another variable like in the above examples.

Just give it a try.

EDIT:

If you need to start form your code, than here is a quick fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char userresponse;
    char x;

    do {
        printf("are you human");
        if(scanf(" %c", &userresponse) ==1){
            if (userresponse == 'y' || userresponse == 'Y') {
                printf("welcome\n");
            }
            printf("type z to repeat\n");
            if(scanf(" %c", &x) != 1){
                printf("Error");
                exit(1);
            }
        }else{
            printf("Error");
            exit(1);
        }

    } while (x == 'z' || x == 'Z');

    return 0;
}
```

As you probably see, I try to avoid your problems.
1) I check scanf for errors

2) i put a space in front of **%c** to avoid '\n'.

3) I check for y and Y and for z and Z.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
int main()
{
  char userresponse;
  char x;

  do
  {
    printf("are you human");
    scanf(" %c", &userresponse);

    if (userresponse == 'y')
        printf("welcome\n");
    else
        printf("please leave\n");

    printf("type z to repeat");
    scanf(" %c", &x);
  }
  while (x == 'z');

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't check scanf and what happens if user press **Y** instead of **y**?

Comment: In my very very humble opinion, the first step is to take non working code and make it work. Then it can be improved. In the process people learn. As long as one is stuck because it does not run, nothing happens. I tend to fix only what is needed to make it run. Otherwise I need to explain too much and confuse people even more.

Comment: I'm agree with you, but if we give an Answer, well we should at least take care of that problem, or at least we can inform the OP. Isn't it :) ?